# Setting up proxy to handle subdomain requests

Tags: nginx, proxy, resources, requests

I have setup a proxy for a site which works with the following `nginx` config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name proxy.example.com;
    access_log /dev/null;
    error_log  /dev/null;

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://thepiratebay.se;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

However on this there are also styles loaded from a subdomain (`static.thepiratebay.se`) which aren't going through my proxy, because it links to the original domain. Is there a way to also let those requests go to my proxy? Do I have to change the contents of the pages when serving it to let them also go through my proxy? If so: how? :) Or is there another (perhaps better) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by replacing the URLs by doing the following in my config:

```
sub_filter 'static.thepiratebay.se' 'static.proxy.example.com';
sub_filter_once off;
```